# Partitioning of $\mathbb N$ into infinitely many subsets with infinite size

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a practice-question in a book I'm currently reading.

[image: The question]

My idea is the following: $A_i := \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \max(\text{primefactors}(n)) = i\}$.
The $A_i$ would be disjoint and each is countably infinite, as you $A_i$ contains $i^k$ for all k greater 0.

Is my idea correct? I'm not really sure.

Comment: And on another note: Is it not possible to use \mathbb{N} in the header or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's no trouble with $\mathbb N$ in the header.  I just put it in for you, you can click edit to see the syntax I used.

Comment: Seems correct to me

Comment: As to your question:  I'm not sure I understand your construction.  Are you only defining $A_i$ for prime $i$?  Maybe you meant to write $\max =p_i$, the $i^{th}$ prime, instead?

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, then not all your $A_i$-s are infinite. For instance, $A_4=\varnothing$.

Comment: You might consider a construction $A_i=\{p_i^k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ with $p_n$ the $n$th prime as a starting point...

Comment: So $A_1= \emptyset$ (because $1$ isn't a prime and no number has $1$ as it's highest prime factor) , $A_2= \{2^k\}$ and $A_3=\{3^k, 2^j3^k\}$ $A_4 = \emptyset$ (no number has $4$ as it's highest prime factor because $4$ isn't prime, $A_5= \{5^k, 2^j5^k, 3^l5^k, 2^j3^l5^k\}$ etc.  ANd $1 \not \in \cup A_i$.  Well, it has problems as *written* but the idea is sound and the holes are easy to fix.  (But there are many other ways to do it.  Yours is, I must admit, a clever and neat idea that will work once you get the kinks out.)

Comment: One of *other ways*, assuming $\mathbb{N}$ begins with $1$: $A_i=\{2^{i-1}(2j-1):j\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Ok, so from what I understand now: I should use the i-th prime instead of i itself. And the set $A_1$ should be $\{1\}$